# Example 1, Section 5.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation, determinant

**Definition:** Let $K$ be a commutative ring with identity and $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Let $D:M_{n\times n}(K)\to K$. We say $D$ is $n$-linear, if $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, $D(\alpha_1,..,c\cdot\alpha_i+\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n)$ $=c\cdot D(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_i,..,\alpha_n)$ $+$ $D(\alpha_1,..,\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_1,..,\alpha_i,..,\alpha_n$ are rows of $A$ and $\alpha’_i\in M_{1\times n}(K)$.

> Example 1. Let $k_1,…,k_n$ be positive integers, $1\leq k_i\leq n$, and let $a\in K$. For each $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over $K$, define $D(A)=aA(1,k_1)\dotsb A(n,k_n)$. Then the function $D:M_n(K)\to K$ is $n$-linear.
>
> **Proof:** For, if we regard $D$ as a function of the $i$th row of $A$, the others being fixed, we may write $D(A)$ $=D(\alpha_i)$ $=A(i,k_i)b$, where $b$ is some fixed element of $K$. Let $\alpha’_i= (A’_{i1}, . . ., A’_{in})$. Then we have $D(c\alpha_i+\alpha’_i)$ $=[cA(i,k_i)+A’(i,k_i)]b$ $=cD(\alpha_i)+D(\alpha’_i)$. Thus $D$ is a linear function of each of the rows of $A$.

**Que:** **(1)** What is $A(i,k_i)$, $\forall i\in J_n$? **(2)** From context I think $b=a\prod_{j\in J_n\setminus \{i\}}A(j,k_j)\in K$. Am I right? **(3)** I don’t really understand following equality: $D(c\alpha_i+\alpha’_i)$ $=[cA(i,k_i)+A’(i,k_i)]b$. I have made some partial progress. Let $A=(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_i,..,\alpha_n)$ and $A’=(\alpha_1,..,\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n)$. Then $c\cdot D(A)+D(A’)$ $=c\cdot D(\alpha_i)+D(\alpha’_i)$ $=c\cdot (A(i,k_i)b)+A’(i,k_i)b’$. To get desired result we conclude, $b’$ $=a\prod_{j\in J_n\setminus \{i\}}A’(j,k_j)$ $= a\prod_{j\in J_n\setminus \{i\}}A(j,k_j)$ $=b$. So $c\cdot (A(i,k_i)b)+A’(i,k_i)b’$ $= [c\cdot (A(i,k_i))+A’(i,k_i)]b$. Let $A’’=(\alpha_1,..,c\alpha_i+\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n )$. We need to show $D(A’’)$ $=D(c\alpha_i +\alpha’_i)$ $= [c\cdot (A(i,k_i))+A’(i,k_i)]b$. Then $D(A’’)$ $=A’’(i,k_i)b’’$ $=A’’(i,k_i)b$ $=[cA_{ik_i}+A’_{ik_i}]b$ $=[cA(i,k_i)+A’(i,k_i)]b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **(1)** What is $A(i,k_i)$, $\forall i\in J_n$

It is any element of row $i$ of $A$.

> **(2)** From context I think $$b=a\prod_{j\in J_n\setminus \{i\}}A(j,k_j)\in K.\tag{1}$$ Am I right?

Yes this is what it is.

> **(3)** I don’t really understand following equality: $D(c\alpha_i+\alpha’_i)$ $=[cA(i,k_i)+A’(i,k_i)]b$.

The authors have defined $D(\alpha_i)$ so we can focus on just the $i$th row. Only $\alpha_i'$ differs from $A$, not the whole matrix.

> Then $c\cdot D(A)+D(A’)$ $=c\cdot D(\alpha_i)+D(\alpha’_i)$ $=c\cdot (A(i,k_i)b)+A’(i,k_i)b’$.

But with the definition of $A'$ which you have used,
$$A’=(\alpha_1,..,\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n)
\tag{2}
$$
and (1), all of the rows except for the $i$ row are the same, so $b'=b$.

> $D(\alpha_1,..,c\cdot\alpha_i+\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n)=c\cdot D(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_i,..,\alpha_n)+D(\alpha_1,..,\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n)$

There is no different $b'$ from $D(A')$.

The point of this is to show that this $D$ function which picks just one element from each row is a valid $n$-linear function on $A(K)$, so we need some other matrix to work with, and they define $D(\alpha_i)$ just to make the notation simpler.

Comment: (1) ohh… I think, you meant $A(i,k_i)$ represent $i$th row & $k_i$th column of $A$. (3) Actually I explicitly stated $A’=(\alpha_1,..,\alpha’_i,..,\alpha_n)$. So $b’=a\prod_{j\in J_n\setminus \{i\} }A’(j,k_j)$. Since $j\neq i$, $A’(j,k_j)= A(j,k_j)$.

Comment: I've rewritten it to remove the errors you pointed out.